# How to change the section header text color in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been actively looking for a solution to do this, and the closest I got was this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
}
```

I put this function in my TableViewController, as I understand it's a UITableViewDelegate method. For context, the UITableViewController I'm using is embedded into a Container View within a UIView. Nothing happens. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you register your header view cell in Section of TableView?? Please show more code

I **recommend** that you should implement your table header view cell in Section like the following steps:

**Step 1**: Create **YourTableHeaderViewCell**

[image]

**Step 2**: Add text label in **YourTableHeaderViewCell.xib**

[image]

**Step 3**: Create the outlet text label in **YourTableHeaderViewCell.swift**

[image]

It **became** like:

```
class YourTableHeaderViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutle weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - Variables
    static var identifier = "YourTableHeaderViewCell"
}
```

**Step 4**: Setup **YourViewController** and **Register** your table header view cell:

[image]

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - View Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableView()
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: YourTableViewHeaderView.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: YourTableViewHeaderView.identifier) // register your table header view cell
        tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: YourTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: YourTableViewCel.identifier) // register your table view cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return // number of your sections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return // number of rows in sections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YourTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCell {
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YourTableViewHeaderView.identifier) as? YourTableViewHeaderView {
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white // Change the text color here
            return cell.contentView
        }
        return UIView()
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not register the header view cell. I simply created the TableView in IB. Would I need to do this in order to change the color?

Comment: Yes, of course. You should create your header view cell separately and register it in TableView, then you could change anything based on your header view cell

Comment: If you don't know how to create table view header view cell, please tell me I will edit my answer above

Comment: Please do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "title"
}
```

And make you sure you are not implementing this at the same time:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    <#code#>
}
```